# Next.js app works on Safari, Chrome and Firefox but give hydration error on Brave Browser

Tags: reactjs, next.js, brave, hydration

I have a simple Next.js app. I am not using any server side options. It works well on Safari, Chrome, Firefox and it s already running on Vercel without any issue.

Today i tried it with Brave browser (the live link works without a problem) and i am getting this error on localhost:3000

I am only using Metamask - Firefox Relay and 1Password extensions with Brave.

Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

I tried to comment out some of the functions and components to catch the issues but, nope..

Error log;

Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.
at removeChild (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11099:18)
at commitDeletionEffectsOnFiber (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24023:15)
at recursivelyTraverseDeletionEffects (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23984:5)
at commitDeletionEffectsOnFiber (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24113:9)
at recursivelyTraverseDeletionEffects (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23984:5)
at commitDeletionEffectsOnFiber (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24113:9)
at recursivelyTraverseDeletionEffects (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23984:5)
at commitDeletionEffectsOnFiber (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24113:9)
at commitDeletionEffects (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23971:5)
at recursivelyTraverseMutationEffects (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24254:9)
at commitMutationEffectsOnFiber (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24341:9)
at recursivelyTraverseMutationEffects (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24268:7)
at commitMutationEffectsOnFiber (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24288:9)
at recursivelyTraverseMutationEffects (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24268:7)
at commitMutationEffectsOnFiber (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24288:9)
at recursivelyTraverseMutationEffects (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24268:7)
at commitMutationEffectsOnFiber (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24341:9)
at recursivelyTraverseMutationEffects (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24268:7)
at commitMutationEffectsOnFiber (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24288:9)
at recursivelyTraverseMutationEffects (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24268:7)
at commitMutationEffectsOnFiber (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24288:9)
at recursivelyTraverseMutationEffects (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24268:7)
at commitMutationEffectsOnFiber (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24288:9)
at recursivelyTraverseMutationEffects (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24268:7)
at commitMutationEffectsOnFiber (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24288:9)
at recursivelyTraverseMutationEffects (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24268:7)
at commitMutationEffectsOnFiber (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24341:9)
at recursivelyTraverseMutationEffects (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24268:7)
at commitMutationEffectsOnFiber (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24288:9)
at recursivelyTraverseMutationEffects (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24268:7)
at commitMutationEffectsOnFiber (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24288:9)
at recursivelyTraverseMutationEffects (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24268:7)
at commitMutationEffectsOnFiber (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24288:9)
at recursivelyTraverseMutationEffects (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24268:7)
at commitMutationEffectsOnFiber (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24288:9)
at recursivelyTraverseMutationEffects (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24268:7)
at commitMutationEffectsOnFiber (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24571:9)
at recursivelyTraverseMutationEffects (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24268:7)
at commitMutationEffectsOnFiber (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24341:9)
at recursivelyTraverseMutationEffects (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24268:7)
at commitMutationEffectsOnFiber (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24288:9)
at recursivelyTraverseMutationEffects (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24268:7)
at commitMutationEffectsOnFiber (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24288:9)
at recursivelyTraverseMutationEffects (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24268:7)
at commitMutationEffectsOnFiber (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24288:9)
at recursivelyTraverseMutationEffects (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24268:7)
at commitMutationEffectsOnFiber (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24341:9)
at recursivelyTraverseMutationEffects (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24268:7)
at commitMutationEffectsOnFiber (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24288:9)
at recursivelyTraverseMutationEffects (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24268:7)
next-dev.js?3515:20 The above error occurred in the  component:

```
at Input2 (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@chakra-ui/input/dist/chunk-GYFRIY2Z.mjs:15:11)
at div
at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@emotion/react/dist/emotion-element-6a883da9.browser.esm.js:57:66)
at commitMutationEffectsOnFiber (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24341:9)
at div
at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@emotion/react/dist/emotion-element-6a883da9.browser.esm.js:57:66)
at commitMutationEffectsOnFiber (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24341:9)
at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@chakra-ui/layout/dist/chunk-O5CRURSQ.mjs:23:5)
at VStack
at div
at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@emotion/react/dist/emotion-element-6a883da9.browser.esm.js:57:66)
at commitMutationEffectsOnFiber (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24341:9)
at CardBody2 (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@chakra-ui/card/dist/chunk-KKEJMMX3.mjs:16:11)
at commitMutationEffectsOnFiber (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24341:9)
at div
at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@emotion/react/dist/emotion-element-6a883da9.browser.esm.js:57:66)
at commitMutationEffectsOnFiber (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24341:9)
at Card2 (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@chakra-ui/card/dist/chunk-S432VF2S.mjs:24:88)
at main
at commitMutationEffectsOnFiber (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24341:9)
at SessionContextProvider (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@supabase/auth-helpers-react/dist/index.js:42:3)
at QueryClientProvider (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@tanstack/react-query/build/lib/QueryClientProvider.mjs:47:3)
at WagmiConfig (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/wagmi/dist/index.js:134:3)
at EnvironmentProvider (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@chakra-ui/react-env/dist/chunk-23XYWYLU.mjs:32:11)
at ColorModeProvider (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@chakra-ui/color-mode/dist/chunk-4DEUOPYU.mjs:28:5)
at ThemeProvider (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@emotion/react/dist/emotion-element-6a883da9.browser.esm.js:96:64)
at ThemeProvider (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@chakra-ui/system/dist/chunk-3ZTTLJBV.mjs:26:11)
at ChakraProvider (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@chakra-ui/provider/dist/chunk-IC3K6TJB.mjs:18:5)
at ChakraProvider2 (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@chakra-ui/react/dist/chunk-DGNA6VRZ.mjs:17:5)
at App (webpack-internal:///./pages/_app.tsx:42:11)
at PathnameContextProviderAdapter (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/adapters.js:62:11)
at commitMutationEffectsOnFiber (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24341:9)
at ReactDevOverlay (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@next/react-dev-overlay/dist/client.js:850:919)
at commitMutationEffectsOnFiber (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24341:9)
at AppContainer (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:171:11)
at Root (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:346:11)
```

React will try to recreate this component tree from scratch using the error boundary you provided, ErrorBoundary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your  component has problem.

You may just add this code beginning of that component, if it fixes, then you find the problem and try to fix what causing that.

```
  const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false);
useEffect(() => setMounted(true), []); if (!mounted) return null;
```